# Accessing files on LAN from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, lan, file-access

As it is mentioned in the title. I would like to build a mechanism allowing me to access different files on LAN and read their metadata values. I don't want to change those files, or create new ones. The problem is I would like to have a web interface for doing that, with a database allowing me to store data about those files for comparison.

1) Is it possible?

2) If it is, where should I start my research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) it is possible, you will have to tackle different security challenges, like impersonation when accessing UNC  shares

2) I would suggest to think about the overall design, if this is really what you need instead of having for example agents locally, on each machine, which would access the files locally, on each machine and would provide certain service based functionality to repot file metadata, do the comparison etc

Comment: What about if I'd self host Web API in the console app, and then send a get request to that API to give me details about the files on the system? I would need to have a separate console web apps for each location, but just one MVC web application to consume the data?

Comment: This could be a solution :)